# Custom code inside <body>

Tags: 8

Is there any way to output code from **module** controller class inside `<body>` in front page ? I need output a javascript code which will look like, lets say:

```
$phpvariable = variable_get('mymodulename_companyid', false);

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("'.$phpvariable.'");
</script>
```

In Drupal 7 I was doing this in file `mymodulename.module` like this.:

```
function mymodulename_init()
{
    $phpvariable = variable_get('mymodulename_companyid', false);

    if($phpvariable){
        drupal_add_js('alert("'.$phpvariable.'");', array(
            'scope' => 'footer',
            'type' => 'inline',
        ));
    }
}
```

Ofcourse now It doesn't work and I cant find the proper method for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a libraries file in your module/theme (foo.libraries.yml in this example).
2. Add a library declaration in your libraries file.
3. In your library declaration point to a javascript file that will contain your logic (foo.js in this example)
4. Attach your library in hook_page_attachments or in a specific render array.
5. Attach your variable to the drupalSettings object.

---

#### foo.libraries.yml

```
baz:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/foo.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
```

---

#### foo.js

```
(function (drupalSettings) {
  alert(drupalSettings.bar.message);
})(drupalSettings);
```

---

#### foo.module

```
foo_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'foo/baz';
  $page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['bar']['message'] = 'Hello World';
}
```

Comment: Your solution is much better than main. One suggestion because I wasn't know this: `$page['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/foo';` should be in your case `$page['#attached']['library'][] = 'modulename/baz';`

Comment: @WalterWhite updated the answer with the correct reference

Answer (score 2):

I think you could go with [hook_page_attachments](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8) instead of [hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7). Of course you would also need to add the javascript in a different way in D8, read here https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843

Comment: Well I'm already using `*.libaries.yml` to include css and js but my js code is generated `if` something and need some values from database. So I have to generate this from controller view (I think) and here is the problem.

Comment: If you need variables in the JavaScript code, couldn't you still that in Twig and use preprocess hooks to provide the variables to the template?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the already mentioned hook_page_attachments() together with #type html_head to create arbitrary elements in .

If it really must be in the body, you can use `hook_page_top` and put anything using #markup, #type inline_template or a real template. See `toolbar_page_top` for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I can't get It work. In my opinion docs are very poor for someone who doesn't know Symfony 2 and Drupal 8. In what file I should put this function? In my `modulename/src/modulenameController.php` it won't work even after clearing the cache. Also what should I `use` in `php` to be able using the `theme.api.php`? After every change I'm clearing the cache and I don't see any changes.

Comment: Drupal 8 just came out, it will take some time docs to be written. And they exist, you might just not find them. hooks are documented on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/hooks/8 for example.

Comment: Thank you for help. I was finally get It work with http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!core!includes!module.inc/group/hooks/8

Answer (score -3):

For all those who in the future will face the same problem. The solution turned out to be trivial.

In module folder create a file `modulename.module`. Inside this file simply add (ofcourse with `<?php` at the begining of file) :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_top().
 *
 * Description
 */
function mymodulename_page_top(array &$page_top) {
    $val = \Drupal::state()->get('phpvariable');

    if($val)
    {
        echo '<script>alert("'.$val.'");</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want javascript code to run in the page then you should use libraries. If you want to pass variables to the javascript use drupalSettings.

Comment: I want to pass variable into javascript code. I also want to check if the variable exists in database. As you can see, above example solves all my problem because code is displayed right after opening the `<body>` tag.

Comment: The above code is considered bad practice. I'll add an answer with the recommended practice.